# How to generate a list of all urls

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy, urls, links

I'd like to display a list of all Urls of my Wordprees site.

I print out a list of all taxonomy terms like this :

```
<?php
// Get all Post
$html = '<h2>Articles</h2>';
query_posts('&showposts=-1&order=ASC');
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    ob_start();
    the_taxonomies(); 
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $html .=  '<a href="' . get_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a><br />';
    $html .= $result . '<br /><br />';
};
$html .= '<br />';
echo $html;
?>
```

Does anyone know how I can do to obtain all correct url (permalink) for all

- Tags
- Category
- Taxonomy terms
- Archives
- Author page
- Posts
- Page
- Others ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: wp codex has everything you need, ex. for tags: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

Comment: There are a lot of functions in the WP Codex. I'm a lost to know exactly which used to achieve this.

Comment: There's no one-function that does all that, you have to get each list separately.